# unable to to open redirected page after facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, session-state

i am using facebook connect under codeigniter.after authentication i want to redirect on success method of my controller
here is my controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('Facebook_model');
}

function index()
{
    $fb_data = $this->session->userdata('fb_data');

    $data = array(
                'fb_data' => $fb_data,
                );

    $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
}

function topsecret()
{
    $fb_data = $this->session->userdata('fb_data');

    if((!$fb_data['uid']) or (!$fb_data['me']))
    {
        redirect('welcome');
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array(
                    'fb_data' => $fb_data,
                    );

        $this->load->view('topsecret', $data);
    }
}
function success()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
}
```

my model for facebook api access:

```
class Facebook_model extends CI_Model {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $config = array(
                    'appId'  => '261066574000678',
                    'secret' => '   79e11f65449988965362f58e9a4aabd7',
                    'fileUpload' => true, // Indicates if the CURL based @ syntax for file uploads is enabled.
                    );

    $this->load->library('Facebook', $config);

    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

    // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
    //
    // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
    // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
    // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.
    $profile = null;
    if($user)
    {
        try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,link,email');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }       
    }

    $fb_data = array(
                    'me' => $profile,
                    'uid' => $user,
                    'loginUrl' => $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(
                        array(
                            'scope' => 'email,user_birthday,publish_stream', // app permissions
                            'redirect_uri' => 'https://sanjay.localhost.com/index.php/welcome/success' // URL where you want to redirect your users after a successful login
                    )
                    ),
                    'logoutUrl' => $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(),
                );

    $this->session->set_userdata('fb_data', $fb_data);
}
}
```

since i am testing this on localhost host,i also edited my host file and changed my localhost hostname to sanjay.localhost.com.redirect happens but not happens..i think may be because of querystring.when redirects happens redirect uri is
=">https://sanjay.localhost.com/index.php/welcome/success?state=ff5712299510defa&code=AQCaD-FAd1shuW#*=*
i am not understanding how to handle state and code inside of query string.
please help.

Comment: Does it redirect back to welcome/success? After authenticating with facebook, what is happening? is it showing any errors?

Comment: @Gavin redirects happens but it says This webpage is not available and browser address comes like this :https://sanjay.localhost.com/index.php/welcome/success?state=ff5712299510defa&code=AQCaD-FAd1shuW#=.i dnt know how to handle this query string

Comment: Look at the `uri_protocol` setting in the `config.php` file. Try setting it to each of the available values (see the comments above it for the available options) and then go to the URL that is failing. I use CodeIgniter for all of my websites and I've never had a problem when mixing both user friendly urls and urls containing querystring values (i.e. paypal payments that return values via the querystring) so it's just a matter of finding out what works ;)

Comment: @Gavin ya but what to do with this querystring value(state and code).how to handle it inside my success method..please please let me know.i am new to this.:(

Comment: i tried as you said.still it not working:(

Comment: @Gavin can I mail you my experiement please have a look.replay me on riya.ahuja68@gmail.com.ill mail you my files

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for contacting me on my blog. First of all, Facebook is discontinued the localhost support. Her is the link https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/128794873890320.

I have not developed any app using codeigniter, I use CakePHP but the auth follow should be same.
1. Create a fb_login function in user controller.
2. This function will follow this logic.
  a. Use `$facebook->getUser()` to get user id.
  b. Then use  `$facebook->api('/me')` to be sure.
3.If you get FacebookApiException then send user to login with Facebook. If you use official SDK then the current url will be added to redirect url.
4.the Facebook will redirect your user after sign in. so you will get data using `$facebook->getUser()`. Save this data in session for further use in you app. then redirect user to you control page or any other page. CakePHP has `setFlash()` function wich show what ever msg set in the control panel in view. I think Codeignator should have some thing like this. If not you can simply set a msg in session and redirect user. Then unset the msg after showing the msg.

Here is full code

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();        
try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) { 
    //echo $e->getMessage();
    $uid = null;
}

$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'publish_stream,offline_access,email'
        ),''
);

if (!$uid) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
//search using uid on your user table to check if the use is returnign user or new user.
if($new_user ==1)
{
    $this->Session->setFlash('please sign up');
    //redirect to sign up
}
else
{
    $this->Session->setFlash('you are good lad');
    //reditect to control panel
}
```